# Displaying a changed image title

Tags: javascript, image, innerhtml, document.write

I'm trying to display the title of my image right underneath the image itself. I have an onClick event in the image that changes the title of the image once you click on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        onClick Handler
    </title>
    <h3 style="text-align:center">onClick Handler</h3>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">
    <img src="NukaCola.jpg" title="Nuka Cola" id="id1" height="550" width="350" onClick="this.title='You Clicked!';"/>
    </br><script>
        var x=document.getElementById("id1");
        document.write(x.title);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I know it's bad form to use document.write( ), and it doesn't even accomplish what I want to do, because I would like to display the new image title after the user has clicked on the image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        onClick Handler
    </title>
    <h3 style="text-align:center">onClick Handler</h3>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">
    <img src=NukaCola.jpg title="Nuka Cola" id="id1" height=550 width=350 onClick="updateTitle(this)"/>
    <p id='id1Text'></p>
    </br>
    <script>
        function updateTitle(img) {
            img.title = 'You clicked!';
            document.getElementById(img.id +'Text').textContent = img.title;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed something: you have a h3 tag declared within the head tag.